# Using counter index to set .hover() and .mouseout() events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make simple five star rating system using Twitter Bootstrap 3 i jQuery. For now, I'm trying to set .hover() and .mouseout() events using counter by writing this code that doesn't work:

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    $('#overall_rating_' + i).hover(function(){
        $('#overall_rating_' + i).removeClass("glyphicon-star-empty").addClass("glyphicon-star");
    });
    $('#overall_rating_' + i).mouseout(function(){
        $('#overall_rating_' + i).removeClass("glyphicon-star").addClass("glyphicon-star-empty");
    });
}
```

Trying to highlight current and previous stars on mouseover. The code is not complete, it would be accompanied by additional sub-counters, but this part doesn't work for now. Any better methods are welcome. What's broken here?

Comment: Perhaps a better name for the question would be "Highlighting current and previous stars on mouseover"?

Comment: The reason your question is being downvoted is because you have not fully explained: your problem, what you have tried, what is happening when you try it, what you want to happen, why you're doing it that way, etc. Questions should be specific and detailed. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: May I delete the question in order to get asking privileges back?

Comment: I am not sure that would work. I would edit the question to improve it and also ask that question on [meta].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment you left on adeneo's answer, this is what you really need (it could probably be optimized a bit):

```
$(".stars").hover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("glyphicon-star-empty")
    $(this).addClass("glyphicon-star");
    $(this).prevAll().removeClass("glyphicon-star-empty")
    $(this).prevAll().addClass("glyphicon-star");
}, function() {
    $(".stars").removeClass("glyphicon-star")
    $(".stars").addClass("glyphicon-star-empty");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/iansan5653/0gqehupv/2/)

Comment: That's what's really needed.

Answer (score 3):

Try something more like this

```
$('[id^=overall_rating_]').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-star-empty glyphicon-star");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ysa8s3vk/)

---

Edited to fit the comments, working on all previous stars etc.

```
var starz = $('[id^=overall_rating_]').hover(function(){
    starz.filter(':lt('+$(this).index()+')')
         .add(this)
         .toggleClass("glyphicon-star-empty glyphicon-star");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ysa8s3vk/2/)

Comment: But I have five stars, and when I hover on, for instance, 3dth star, the 1st and second stars should be full stars also.

Comment: @mpet - Your question doesn't mention any of that at all. If that's an important part of the issue, then you should update your question with more detail.

Comment: Nice attribute selecting -- I wouldn't have thought of that

Comment: I'm in doubt which of the answers to select, adeneo's or @Ian's

Answer (score 2):

You need to add anonymous functional call to closure `i` variable:

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    ( function( i ) {
        $('#overall_rating_'+i).hover(function(){
            $('#overall_rating_' + i).removeClass("glyphicon-star-empty").addClass("glyphicon-star");
        });
        $('#overall_rating_'+i).mouseout(function(){
            $('#overall_rating_' + i).removeClass("glyphicon-star").addClass("glyphicon-star-empty");
        });
    })( i );
}
```